line and tags/labels with plugin-annotation@3
chartjs with annotation: multiple vertical lines at any x-position, with tags.
Example WORKS with 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@1'
however NOT with 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@1': line tags are missing.
Chartjs version in both cases is chartjs-4.x.x
short: tags OK with plugin-annotation@1 - NO tags with plugin-annotation@3
Example:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chart.js Line Chart with Annotations</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>plugin-annotation@1 - no tags with plugin-annotation@3</p>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
    // labels from 1 to 35
    const labels = Array.from({ length: 35 }, (_, i) => (i + 1).toString());
    // sample data for the chart
    const dataPoints = labels.map(label => Math.random() * 100);

    // Data for chart
    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Sample Data',
        data: dataPoints,
        borderColor: 'blue',
        fill: false
      }]
    };

    // Config for chart
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          x: { beginAtZero: true },
          y: { beginAtZero: true }
        },
        plugins: {
          annotation: {
            annotations: genVertLines(labels)
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // Generate vertical lines at all x-positions ending with '3'
    function genVertLines(labels) {
      const vertLines = labels.filter(label => label.endsWith('3')).map((label, index) => ({
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'vertical',
          scaleID: 'x',
          value: label,
          borderColor: 'red',
          borderWidth: 2,
          label: {
            content: "Label-"+label,
            enabled: true,
          }
        }));
      return vertLines;
    }

    // Create the chart
    window.onload = function() {
      const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>

I was seraching for examples if line with tags, however only found for plugin-annotation1.0.2
Thanks for reading and comments.

Solution:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chart.js Line Chart with Annotations</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4"></script>               
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-annotation@3"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
// labels from 1 to 35
const labels = Array.from({ length: 35 }, (_, i) => (i + 1).toString());
// sample data for the chart
const dataPoints = labels.map(label => Math.random() * 100);

// Data for chart
const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Sample Data',
        data: dataPoints,
        borderColor: 'blue',
        fill: false
    }]
};

const vertLines = genVertLines(labels, '3');
console.log(vertLines);

// Config
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            annotation: {
                annotations:    
                    vertLines,
            }
        }
    }
};

function genVertLines(labels, sfx) {
    const vLines = labels.filter(label => label.endsWith(sfx)).map((label, index) => ({
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'vertical',
        scaleID: 'x',
        value: label,
        label: {
            content: "Label-"+label,
            display: true,
        }
    }));
    return vLines;
}

// Create the chart
window.onload = function() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, config);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>

Result:

